# installation issues on google plugin

Tags: eclipse

I am facing constant issues on google plugin installation in Eclipse. This time it is reporting on core runtime.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

```
Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)
  Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Google Managed APIs Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Project Hosting Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Project Hosting Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Subclipse Support Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.subclipse 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Suite Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Suite Plugin 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r42)
    To: bundle com.google.gdt.eclipse.managedapis 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.7 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e37.feature.feature.group 3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.gph.subclipse [3.3.0.v201307162142-rel-r37]
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Need another plugin, M2E-Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno), go to marketplace and install this plugin, then try install gwt plugin again. Gook Luck

Answer (score 0):

Was going to use GWT for first time, and got this same problem.
Solution that is far from perfect, but worked for me, was upgrading Eclipse from Indigo(3.7) to Kepler(4.3), and installing correct plugin for Kepler.
Just remember to backup your old Eclipse, and you will need Java 1.7

Cheers